# Understanding CPP pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, integer

if

```
int number[];
int *tommy;
```

then whats the difference in the following statements? will both the statements not copy the address of number to tommy?

```
tommy = &number;
```

OR

```
tommy = number;
```

EDIT: sorry guys I meant int array rather than just int.

Comment: The second one won't compile.

Comment: To learn basics like this, you should probably pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Everyone answering this question seems to have missed that `number` is an array. The second compiles, the first is a type error.

Comment: @john: That's because it wasn't an array until a minute ago. Now it's an array of unknown size, so it still won't compile.

Comment: Oh well, fundamental edits to the question without explanation. I very rarely do this but -1 from me.

Comment: @Firdous, I would ask this again, but this time ask what you really mean, and try to compile the code before you ask the question.

Comment: @john one might not have the dev environment anytime, the purpose of question is to grasp the concept, if you think question is below standards you are welcome to down vote!

Comment: @Firdous, it's not really about the standard of the question, its just that because of the edit to the question, the answers will be extremely confusing to anyone subsequently reading this. Now you've acknowledged the edit I'm removed my down vote. Still think you might ask again though.

Comment: @Firdous There are several online compilers available, e.g. [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example to compile, the array will need a size:

```
int number[1];
```

since you can't create a variable of unknown size.

```
tommy = &number;

error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[1]’ to ‘int*’ in assignment
```

This should not compile. `&number` is a pointer to an array, which is not convertible to a pointer to `int`, so cannot be assigned to a variable of that type.

```
tommy = number;
```

This is fine. When used in an expression, an array can be converted to a pointer to its first element. That pointer type is `int*`, the same as `tommy`, so the assignment is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The first one assigns the address of `number` into `tommy`. The second one tries to assign the number `number` into the pointer `tommy`, and it should fail to compile.

**EDIT**

With the edit, it's the other way round: the first one should not compile. An address of an int array is of type `int (*)[size]`, which cannot be converted to `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

`int number;` defines an integer `number`. `int *tommy;` defines `tommy` to be a pointer pointing to an integer.

`tommy = &number;` Assigns the address of `number` to `tommy`. `*tommy` will give the actual number.

`tommy = number` stores the value of `number` in `tommy`. One, there should be a compilation error and on top of it, if you succeed to store `number` into `tommy`, then `*tommy` will try to deference from an invalid location whose address is same as the content of `number` and leads to segmentation fault.

**Postscript**

I am tempted to think if you saw an example as this

```
int a[10];
int *tommy;

tommy = a; // This will work
```

In this example, `a` is the name of the array and is equivalent to the address of array or the first element of the array i.e. `&a[0]`. Hence, storing `a` into `tommy` is valid.

Comment: thanks for interpreting rightly, so would tommy = a and tommy = &a be similar?

Comment: Yes. `a`, the name of the array would be same as the address of the array `&a` and is also the address of the first element of the array `&a[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The first assignment is correct - it assigns the address of `number` to the pointer `tommy`.

The second assignment will assign the *value* of `number` to the pointer `tommy`.

Answer (score 0):

No, they won't, `&` is the `reference operator` or `address of` it will take the address of the variable you prea-append it with, so this does what you want:

```
tommy = &number
```

when you just use plain `number` it just return the integer value stored in number, which won't compile. This [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) on pointers goes into a lot more details.

`Update:`

So after the edit to the question, this will not compile without a size:

```
int number[];
```

this is valid:

```
int number[10];
```

So now it is reversed, this is valid and will compile:

```
tommy = number ;
```

The second line attempts to treat an array of integers as a single integer and the compiler will not allow this and so it is not valid:

```
tommey = &number ;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the two are fundamentally different. The expression `&number` evaluates to the *address* at which the value of `number` is stored, whereas the expression `number` evaluates directly to the value itself.

Suppose that the *value* of number is 42, and that it is stored att *adress* 1024 in memory. Memory is linear*, so it will look something like this:

```
+--------+ Address 0
| ...... |
+--------+
|   42   | Address 1024 (value is stored here)
+--------+
| ...... |
+--------+ Address xxxx
```

Now, the statement `tommy = &number;` will assign the value 1024 to `tommy`, since `&number == 1024`, the address of `number`.

The other statement, provided it compiles at all, will assign the (nonsensical) value 42 (the value of `number`) to `tommy`. Any attempts to dereference (access the data pointed to by) `tommy` are likely to generate a segmentation fault, because 42 is (probably) not a valid address.

*At least, the operating system will give you the illusion that your address space is linear and contiguous.